Computer ONLY translation and rotation (Rigid Euclidean transformation)
I have two images with matching descriptors (if necessary), and I would like to compute a matrix that performs a rotation and translation from img1 to img2. The most important part is to remove all scaling factors. Ideally, I can compute the translation and rotation separately or if there is a function in OpenCV to perform both, that would be better. The two images are images from a homography frame, already trimmed and cropped.
Some functions I have tried are cv2.estimateAffine2D and estimateAffinePartial2D, but they both seem to apply scaling scalars across the diagonals of the matrix. I would be ideal to see the translation and rotation separately.
EDIT: It seems that cv2.estimateAffine2D does exactly this function.

in the past there was a cv2.estimateRigigTransformation function. It was replaced by something else, probably by the cv2.estimateAffine2D
